# Characterization of homomorphisms on a group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $A$ a commutative ring with identity, and $R = A[G]$ the group algebra of $G$ over $A$.  I was just thinking about something and wanted to write down my thoughts to make sure it was correct.  If $f$ is any $A$-algebra homomorphism from $R$ to $A$, then $$1 = f(1_G) = f(g)f(g^{-1})$$

which shows that $f(g) \neq 0$ for any $g \in G$.  Thus $f$ induces a group homomorphism $G \rightarrow A^{\ast}$.  Conversely, a group homomorphism $h: G \rightarrow A^{\ast}$ induces an $A$-algebra homomorphism $R \rightarrow A$ by the formula $\sum\limits_{g \in G} a_g g \mapsto \sum\limits_{g \in G} a_g h(g)$.

In other words, $A[G]$ has the property that there is a bijection

$$\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Grp}}(G,A^{\ast}) \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{A-\textrm{alg}}(A[G],A)$$

which is natural in $G$ and $A$.  Since $A^{\ast}$ is abelian, a homomorphism of $G$ into $A^{\ast}$ is the same thing as a homomorphism of $G/[G,G]$ into $A^{\ast}$.  So we really have a bijection:

$$\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{ab}}(G/[G,G],A^{\ast}) \rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_{A-\textrm{alg}}(A[G],A)$$

Is there a more abstract study of group rings that this kind of reasoning might lead us to?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Can you clarify what you want to know?